# How to implement reverse circular array from index position in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, reverse, circular-dependency

I want to get last 12 months from current month using typescript.

like suppose current month is Jule then my output should be ['August','September','October','November','December','January','February','March','April','May','June','July']

like suppose my array is let myarr=['a','b','c','d'] and i want data from index position 2 then output array should be ['c','b','a','d'].

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Use below code snippet as arr is your array and N  index position from where //need to reverse data on graph x axis + 1
reverseCircularArray(arr: any, N: number) {
  //initialise 2 array
  let firstArr = arr.slice(0, N);
  let secondArr = arr.slice(N);

  // return the circular array
  return [...secondArr, ...firstArr];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to reverse anything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with modulus % operator

```
const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
const arr = [];
const startMonth = 7;//Aug index

for (let i = 0; i < 12; ++i){
   arr.push(months[(i+startMonth) % months.length]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
const arr = [];
const startMonth = 7;//August index

for (let i = 0; i < 12; ++i){
   arr.push(months[(i+startMonth) % months.length]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

```js
const arr1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
const arr = [];
const startMonth = 2;//Aug index

for (let i = 0; i <= 3; ++i){
   arr.push(arr1[(i+startMonth) % arr1.length]);
}
console.log(arr);
```